# An example of Markov chain with no closed class?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

**What is an example of Markov chain with no closed communicating class?**

Closed class means that once we are in that class, there would be no escape from it.

I am thinking that an example would be the 1d random walk. But the problem is that the Markov chain in 1d random walk would be consisted a single class.

The second example that I can think of is 
$0\Rightarrow1\Rightarrow2\Rightarrow3\Rightarrow4\dots\Rightarrow1000\Rightarrow\dots\Rightarrow\infty$.  In this example, every state is a class and that there will be no return.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question.

Comment: Not sure. If you mean an ergodic set, then I agree. But in your second example (walk on the integers), the closed set could be the set of integers. You never leave the set of integers, hence, the set of integers is a closed class. (But I don't think it's an ergodic set.)